# Is there a way to tell a nodejs server to discard the query string from a browser request?

Tags: node.js, http, server

### The problem

I would like my users to be able to share their work in my web application with each other simply by copy/pasting the full URL from the address bar. I pass a big compressed string as a URL query variable.

The big compressed string can be many KiBs in size—naturally, this triggers an HTTP 431 error (Request Header Fields Too Large).

Ultimately, I want to use the query string in the URL for the client only. The server does not need the data, so I don't want the server to waste resources processing it.

Is it possible to intercept the request with node at a low level and ignore the full url? So even if the url is `foo.com/?bar=[blah blah blah]`, I'd like the server to act like it just got `foo.com` for the url

**Note**: I do NOT want to simply increase the --max-http-header-size or otherwise allow larger amounts of data to go to the server.

### My attempt

The most promising thing I have tried is listening for `clientError` from the HTTP module so I can at least detect the 431 error. It doesn't feel like the right way to handle this, though:

```
//I do NOT want to set the maxHeaderSize option for this
var server = http.createServer((req,res) => {
    console.log("got request");

    res.write(JSON.stringify(req.url));
    res.end();
});
server.listen(3000);
server.on("clientError", (err, socket) => {
    console.log("Client error!", socket.writable, err.code);
    if (socket.writable) {
        if(err.code === 'HPE_HEADER_OVERFLOW'){
            //not sure what I would do here

            //doing socket.write has not worked for me
            //doing socket.end has not worked for me
        }else{
            socket.write("HTTP/1.1 400 Client Error\r\n");
            socket.write("Connection: close\r\n");
            socket.write("\r\n");
        }
    }
    socket.destroy(err);
})
```

Comment: Since you're sharing lots of data, have you considered dropping the whole URL idea? Why not create a text box for import/export on the website itself?

Comment: An import/export built into the app is the fallback plan but I’d prefer not to do that.

Comment: I suggest a method that uses the fragment identifier, check out my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a tacky answer, but it should work. I maintain that if the data you are sending is large, you should implement a dedicated import/export mechanism.

If you insist—there is indeed a way to pass information in a URL without sending it over the wire. It is defined in [RFC 1808](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1808.html) under section 2.4.1. It is the **fragment identifier**.

```
<scheme>://<net_loc>/<path>;<params>?<query>#<fragment>
```

We are interested in the fragment bit here. We can pass fragments in URLs by appending a hashtag (#) at the end of the URL and inputting the data.

As such, I suggest including your long compressed data at the end of your URL as such:

```
https://example.com/my/path/site.html#bG90cyBvZiBkYXRhIGhlcmU...
```

### Reading the fragment on the client

On the client side, the fragment data should be populated at `window.location.hash`.

```
if (window.location.hash) {
    // fragment exists and is stored in the ``hash'' variable
    do_something(window.location.hash);
} else {
    // nothing to load
}
```

### A fair warning

I've glanced through the spec, and it doesn't seem to indicate a max size for the fragment identifier. However, keep in mind that it was not designed for this purpose and different clients may handle long fragments in different ways.

Comment: My initial tests seemed to work out using this method, but I'm running into problems on mobile safari. I would REALLY like to solve this issue on the server, but this might be as good as it gets and I'll just have to implement a dedicated import/export as suggested.
On mobile safari it seems to clamp the hash down to around 2000 characters. ( I wish I could tell the server to clamp the url length instead of returning an error)